# Cannot access proxy when http_proxy is set

Tags: terminal, network, proxy

I recently upgraded to macOS Ventura from Catalina and terminal commands suddenly stopped accepting proxies. I use ClashX for proxy. Currently chrome connects to that proxy but the terminal doesn't.
The commands to set variables up are as follows in `.zshrc`:

```
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890 http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890 all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890
```

However, after getting a new terminal session it seems like it was unable to access anything.
Pinging `github.com` returns `Request timeout for icmp_seq`. I was trying to `brew install` and I got

```
Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/llvm/blobs/sha256:c0a14a92f8b6a
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 127.0.0.1:7890
```

when trying to install `llvm`.
Here's the output running `scutil --proxy`:

```
<dictionary> {
  ExceptionsList : <array> {
    0 : 192.168.0.0/16
    1 : 10.0.0.0/8
    2 : 172.16.0.0/12
    3 : 127.0.0.1
    4 : localhost
    5 : *.local
    6 : timestamp.apple.com
  }
  ExcludeSimpleHostnames : 0
  HTTPEnable : 1
  HTTPPort : 7890
  HTTPProxy : 127.0.0.1
  HTTPSEnable : 1
  HTTPSPort : 7890
  HTTPSProxy : 127.0.0.1
  ProxyAutoConfigEnable : 0
  SOCKSEnable : 1
  SOCKSPort : 7890
  SOCKSProxy : 127.0.0.1
}
```

`git`, on the other hand, accepts the proxy when I config globally:

```
http.sslverify=false
http.proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890
https.proxy=https://127.0.0.1:7890
```

I'm so confused. What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Ping doesn't use proxies, so that's not a relevant test. The error from `brew install` indicates it's trying to connect to the proxy a the correct address and port, but running into some sort of error. Would it help to run the http, https, and socks proxy protocols on different ports?

Comment: Hello bro, have you had resovled it? Same question for me!